# Parsing an non-uniform but CSV-ish textfile

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse the following file (exported transactions from my local bank):

```
Clnr   Kontonr     Konto                Valuta  Bokföringsdatum  Transaktionsdatum  Referens                            Kontohändelse                   Belopp
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-30         13-09-30           Hyresgästför                        Autogiro                        -15,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-30         13-09-30           SPOTIFY SPOTIFY                     Kortköp/uttag                   -19,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-30         13-09-30           +46123456789                        Swish mottagen                   80,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-30         13-09-30           PRIS NYCKELKUND                     Debiteringsavgift               -49,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-27         13-09-27           12345678                            direktbetalning                -301,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-27         13-09-27           Unionen                             Bg-bet. via internet           -125,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-26         13-09-26           123456789012345                     Överföring                   -1 000,00
```

But I can't seem to create a proper regex for it. The goal is to extract columns 5, 6, 7 and 9 (if all can be extracted it would be a bonus, of course), but column 7 is the really tricky one, since the file isn't CSV and column 7 can contain multiple words. Column 8 is not predictable, but I think I found most of the relevant possibilities in the example above.

Any tips on how to successfully parse this file? Obviously my regex is not enough. :-(

If it makes any difference, I'd prefer if it could be solved in Python or maybe even POSIX (grep/sed/etc).

Comment: Since the file seems to have a fixed width for the columns you should be able to get hold of individual values from the columns by slicing each line string with the starting and end position of each column.

Comment: Why not get a fix width substring for each line? Something like `line[48:57]` to get the 4th column.

Comment: Have you tried splitting it on a `\t`? `import csv; with open('foo.txt') as f: reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'); rows = list(reader); print(rows);`

Comment: Man I feel stupid now. Even for a longer file the start/end for each column seems to be fixed. I was assuming that I couldn't rely on fixed widths but maybe I can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of it, this is how you can parse this format "automagically":

```
import re

# find out spaces' positions common to all rows
spaces = sorted(set.intersection(*[
    set(m.end() for m in re.finditer(ur'\s', line))
    for line in data
]))

# split by these positions
for line in data:
    row = []
    p = 0
    for s in spaces:
        row.append(line[p:s])
        p = s
    row.append(line[p:])
    row = filter(len, map(unicode.strip, row))
    print ' | '.join(row) # or whatever you want...
```

For your data:

```
data = u"""
Clnr   Kontonr     Konto                Valuta  Bokföringsdatum  Transaktionsdatum  Referens                            Kontohändelse                   Belopp
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-30         13-09-30           Hyresgästför                        Autogiro                        -15,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-30         13-09-30           SPOTIFY SPOTIFY                     Kortköp/uttag                   -19,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-30         13-09-30           +46123456789                        Swish mottagen                   80,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-30         13-09-30           PRIS NYCKELKUND                     Debiteringsavgift               -49,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-27         13-09-27           12345678                            direktbetalning                -301,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-27         13-09-27           Unionen                             Bg-bet. via internet           -125,00
12345  1234567890  vardagskonto         SEK     13-09-26         13-09-26           123456789012345                     Överföring                   -1 000,00
""".strip().splitlines()
```

this prints:

```
Clnr | Kontonr | Konto | Valuta | Bokföringsdatum | Transaktionsdatum | Referens | Kontohändelse | Belopp
12345 | 1234567890 | vardagskonto | SEK | 13-09-30 | 13-09-30 | Hyresgästför | Autogiro | -15,00
12345 | 1234567890 | vardagskonto | SEK | 13-09-30 | 13-09-30 | SPOTIFY SPOTIFY | Kortköp/uttag | -19,00
12345 | 1234567890 | vardagskonto | SEK | 13-09-30 | 13-09-30 | +46123456789 | Swish mottagen | 80,00
12345 | 1234567890 | vardagskonto | SEK | 13-09-30 | 13-09-30 | PRIS NYCKELKUND | Debiteringsavgift | -49,00
12345 | 1234567890 | vardagskonto | SEK | 13-09-27 | 13-09-27 | 12345678 | direktbetalning | -301,00
12345 | 1234567890 | vardagskonto | SEK | 13-09-27 | 13-09-27 | Unionen | Bg-bet. via internet | -125,00
12345 | 1234567890 | vardagskonto | SEK | 13-09-26 | 13-09-26 | 123456789012345 | Överföring | -1 000,00
```

Comment: I wish I understood the first bit of your solution, but I really like that your solution works for arbitrary spaced inputs. I ended up using the more simple approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` to separate the values. Example:

```
import re

raw_data = open("test.csv").readlines()
header = raw_data[0]
data = raw_data[1:]

for line in data:
        values = re.split("\s{2,}", line.strip()) # splits by two or more spaces
        print list(values) # show as a list
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using, thanks! The solution proposed by thg435 is better but yours I fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

why not this regex:

```
(.*?)(  +|\r\n|\n|$)
```

it seems all columns are seperated by 2 spaces